# How can I take char value with int?

Tags: c++, char, integer

How can I take char value with int value?

For example I want enter <kbd>+</kbd> because I'm making a calculator program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int a;

    std::cin >> a;
    std::cout << a;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not take a `char` value with a `char` instead?

Answer (score 0):

you can see the value of `int` into `char` by static casting your `int` to `char`.

`std::cout << static_cast<char>(a);`